# Acessors get set

Tags: c#, int, accessor

Here the score, i am developing an application in c# I have hit a problem where I am trying to increment and integer but i seem to getting the same number back every time.

I have a class "class1" which contains the following:

```
public class class1
{
    public int id;

    public int Outid
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public string OutputName
    {
        get { return Outid.ToString("000"); }
        set { this.Outid.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

And another, which in short contains a method which cycles through a workbooks worksheets, in that method there are two lines which are relevant to my problem

```
class1.id++;

console.write(class1.id)
```

The write line is always 1, I have been playing around for a few hours now and cant see the woods for the trees. I would imagine it would have to be something to do with the properties in `class1`.

Comment: the setter of `OutputName` makes no sense... besides that, what is the context of the two lines you posted? with the code given (notice that you are never using the properties of `class1`!?) I see no reason for the behaviour you describe

Comment: Are you newing up a new Class1 everytime before you do a Console.Write ? If you are using the same instance of Class1 it will increment correctly.

Comment: The first of the two lines I would have hoped that it would add 1 to "id" which is in "class1". The second was just to prove the right number is coming out. Unable to post any more the code related to cycling through workbook. Excuse the typos, I don't have access to the code.

Comment: It must be the way i have used get set as the cycling through work books is fine. Can i ask for a suggestion, if the `OutputName` doesnt make sense?

Comment: @ManWithNoName When you call `class1.id++` you're using the field directly, not the property, so there's no way this has anything to do with the property accessors.

Answer (score 3):

The value will always be 1 if you're re-instantiating the class every time, for example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    class1.id++;
    Console.WriteLine(class1.id);
}
```

This will output 1, ten times to the console, because on each iteration you're creating a new `Class1` whose `id` field always starts out at the default value, 0.

However, if you instantiate it once, and then reuse the class, the `id` field will be updated as you expect:

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    class1.id++;
    Console.WriteLine(class1.id);
}
```

This will output the numbers 1 through 10 to the console. And of course, the same thing works if you use the property rather than the field:

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    class1.Outid++;
    Console.WriteLine(class1.Outid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write `class1` you say that you want to indicate a static field/property/method. You must create an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest that you have something like

```
public class Class1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

then you can call it like

```
var c = new Class1();

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   c.id += 1;
}

Console.Writeline(c.id.ToString());
```